# how to add two fields from different tables together SQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, concatenation, group-concat

I am trying to create a report that displays reasons something went wrong on a job i.e. goods were damaged, undelivered etc.

```
select
  group_concat(distinct
       concat(
        'sum((select count(jp1.MemReason) from job_pieces jp1 
         left join unapprovedquotereasons un1 on un1.Description =jp1.MemReason
         where jp1.jobid=jn.id and un1.Code=''',
         un.Code,
        '''))  AS `',
        un.Code, '`'
        )
   ) into @sql
   FROM customer c
   LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
   LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
   LEFT JOIN unapprovedquotereasons un on un.Description = jp.DebriefReason
   WHERE c.Company_ID = 171;
```

So this sql statement displays the reasons as a header and under this column it displays how many times that reason was used for each company:

[image]

So in the image we can see the second company used the reason "Damaged" twice. 
The problem I am having is the reasons are also saved in a different table in the database. So I also need to count a field called `MemOutturnReason` from the `job_new` table. How do I add these two fields together?

Generated SQL:

```
select
        sum((select count(jp1.MemReason) from job_pieces jp1 
                   left join unapprovedquotereasons un1 on un1.Description =jp1.MemReason
                   where jp1.jobid=jn.id and un1.Code='DAM'))  AS `DAM`,sum((select count(jp1.MemReason) from job_pieces jp1 
                   left join unapprovedquotereasons un1 on un1.Description =jp1.MemReason
                   where jp1.jobid=jn.id and un1.Code='SIZE'))  AS `SIZE`,sum((select count(jp1.MemReason) from job_pieces jp1 
                   left join unapprovedquotereasons un1 on un1.Description =jp1.MemReason
                   where jp1.jobid=jn.id and un1.Code='GOODS'))  AS `GOODS`,sum((select count(jp1.MemReason) from job_pieces jp1 
                   left join unapprovedquotereasons un1 on un1.Description =jp1.MemReason
                   where jp1.jobid=jn.id and un1.Code='NOTREV'))  AS `NOTREV`
    FROM customer c
    LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
WHERE jn.IsActive = 1 AND c.Company_ID = 171  GROUP BY jn.JobOwnerID
```

Comment: could you paste the generated SQL? It will help to understand what exactly is being run and how to change it

Comment: @vmachan I added the generated SQL to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the fields in your database tables, hope this will give you an idea. It is a pseudo code.  Try this with modifications according to your db tables and fields,

```
   SELECT c.name as Name, count(jp.MemReason) as DAMAGED, count(jp.something) as PROB
   FROM customer c
   LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON jn.JobOwnerID = c.ID
   LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON jp.JobID = jn.ID
   LEFT JOIN unapprovedquotereasons un on un.Description = jp.DebriefReason
   GROUP BY c.Company_ID;
```

Comment: I basically just need to added to added `jp.MemReason` and `jn.MemOutturnReason` together if they have the same description